# How to disable high dpi support on Windows 7?

Tags: delphi, manifest, delphi-10.2-tokyo, highdpi

I have an older application for which I want to use DPI virtualization on Windows 7 (also known as *blurry form scaling*). To try this in an example project, I did the following:

- enable 125 % text display on a Windows 7 machine
- disabled any manifest for that project
- read `Monitor.PixelsPerInch` with a result of `120`

I tried some things, but I was unable to get a result of `96` dpi here:

- used `<dpiAware>false</dpiAware>` in an internal or external supplied manifest
- changed application compatibility settings
- changed windows theme

I additionaly thought that `SetProcessDPIAware` is called somwhere in the `VCL`. I found `System.win.HighDpi` which contains `SetProcessDPIAware` in its initialization block, but this unit is not included in my minimal sample.

Sample manifest (setting `dpiAware` seems to be ignored):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <security>
    <requestedPrivileges>
      <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
    </requestedPrivileges>
  </security>
 </trustInfo>
    <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3"> 
    <windowsSettings> 
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">False</dpiAware> 
    </windowsSettings> 
  </application> 
</assembly>
```

Comment: Make sure that the manifest settings in the Application project options are set correct for all build configurations, especially the common ones.

Comment: I used resource hacker to confirm that the correct manifest is embedded.

Comment: You absolutely don't want to remove the manifest. You just want to make sure that the manifest declares `dpiAware` as `false`. But IIRC this means that the application is not expected to be aware of font scaling values other than 100% and 125%. These were the standard font scalings supported in XP and I think you are expected to handle them.